# Replacing String Values Solution Explanation in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Could anyone explain how this code works? Particularly the callback function, I am confused as to why it loops through the entire input rather just part of the input

```
function DNAStrand(dna){
  return dna.replace(/[ACGT]/g, function(l){ return pairs[l] });
}

var pairs = {
  A:'T',
  T:'A',
  G:'C',
  C:'G'
};
```

Also, This was my solution for the same task(on code wars) my code compiled in 4 ms which I thought was pretty good!

```
function DNAStrand(dna){
  //your code here
  var dnaArray = dna.slice("");
  var compliment = [];  //push all values here
  for(i=0; i<dnaArray.length; i++){    //loops through whole array
    if(dnaArray[i] === 'T'){compliment.push('A')}
    if(dnaArray[i] === 'A'){compliment.push('T')}
    if(dnaArray[i] === 'G'){compliment.push('C')}
    if(dnaArray[i] === 'C'){compliment.push('G')}
  }
  var result = compliment.join("");
  return result;
}
```

Besides for being less elegant then the first solution, is there anything wrong with this solution versus the other if they both produce the same outcome?  Just trying to understand general rules about best practices!

Comment: `as to why it loops through all of the string rather than just one part of the string` What do you mean by this, can you elaborate more? It's not clear what's confusing to you, what were you thinking "one part" of the string would be?

Comment: Your secondary snippet should at least use if else chains.  If the first if evaluates to true, there's no reason to perform the other ifs.  Also that whole for loop could be a map() usage.  However, you're asking two different questions, which makes this lean towards being too broad.  Choose which question you want to ask and ask just one at a time

Comment: There are also api docs for javascript functions.  If you want to know how a function works, they are the first place you should hit up.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The regex `/[ACGT]/g` performs a global (from the `/g` flag) search for `A`, `C`, `G`, or `T` within the `dna` string
2. For each match (of a single `A`, `C`, `G`, or `T`), it does a replacement using the callback function
3. The callback function looks up the input character (`A`, `C`, `G`, or `T`) in `pairs` and return the corresponding value